# Single word for "going along with the crowd"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe the behaviour where you do something because everyone is also doing this, to the point where you do it without any clear reason?

Comment: ***Herd mentality*** to 'describe the behavior' of people esp., to the point of leaving all reason.

Comment: **cooperation**

Comment: Relevant video on conformity: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrNIuFrso8I

Answer (score 35):

Perhaps you're looking for **conforming**:

> **2 a**:  to be obedient or compliant—usually used with to <*conform* to another's wishes>
>    **b**:  to act in accordance with prevailing standards or customs <the pressure to *conform*>
>
> —source [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform)

Or **conformity** as a noun:

> **3**: action in accordance with some specified standard or authority <*conformity* to social custom>
>
> —source [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conformity)

A person who routinely conforms to established standards or authorities, without questioning those standards or authorities, would be called a **conformist**, and adopts a stance of **conformism**:

> **1.** a person who conforms, especially unquestioningly, to the usual practices or standards of a group, society, etc.
>
> —source [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conformism)

Answer (score 12):

Words to describe that behavior? I can't think of anything other than "bandwagoning" and "bandwagon effect."

Words that describe a person who engages in such behavior are much more plentiful though, and include "lemming," "sheep," or "trendster." "Yes man" might be appropriate, depending on what exactly you're going for and "fashion victim" is perfect for certain contexts.

Answer (score 12):

There is a term to describe exactly this type of impressionable personality: ***sheeple*** - a linguistic blend of *sheep* and *people*.

> sheeple  (ˈʃiːp ə l)
>
> — n
>   informal  people who tend to follow the majority in matters of opinion, taste, etc
>
> [C20: from sheep  + people ]

The phenomenon is probably best captured by Orwell's term ***groupthink***.

> 1.
>   the practice of approaching problems or issues as matters that are best dealt with by consensus of a group rather than by individuals acting independently; conformity.
>
> 2.
>   the lack of individual creativity, or of a sense of personal responsibility, that is sometimes characteristic of group interaction.

Comment: I've never seen sheeple used in a non-sarcastic way.

Comment: Just as well - sheep-like behaviour is not very complimentary.

Answer (score 8):

Consider **[herd behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_behavior)**

> Herd behavior describes how individuals in a group can act together without planned direction

Also **[mob mentality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mob_Mentality)** or **herd mentality**.

Answer (score 6):

**Conforming** is the most correct... but the act of giving in could be termed **Acquiescing**, **acquiescence**, to **acquiesce**.

That would imply that there were at least initially some hesitance, or resistance to conform.

Answer (score 5):

Lemming

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/lemming-like - definition #2

> a member of any large group following an unthinking course towards mass destruction

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lemming.asp

> In the animal kingdom, a lemming is a rodent known for periodic mass migrations that occasionally end in drowning.

Comment: A good suggestion stressing the mindless aspect of a some conformists. In Toby Frosts novel "[Wrath of the Lemming Men](http://myrmidonbooks.com/wrath-of-the-lemming-men/)" Space Captain Smith of the British Space Empire (sic) engages the lemming-people of Yull.

Answer (score 2):

***Herd mentality*** describes such behavior of people esp., to the point of leaving out all reason.

*[Herd mentality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_mentality)* (WP)

> Herd mentality, or mob mentality, describes how people are influenced by their peers to adopt certain behaviors, follow trends, and/or purchase items. Examples of the herd mentality include stock market trends, superstition, home décor, etc. Social psychologists study the related topics of group intelligence, crowd wisdom, and decentralized decision making. *mob mentality*; *flocking*; *mass hysteria*.

Answer (score 2):

Sequacious is the answer that seems missing here. I thing this would be the best word to describe this.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequacious

Answer (score 1):

Compliant?
A compliant person agrees and obeys - sometimes excessively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idiom "jump on the bandwagon".

> *jump on the bandwagon*
>   — imitate what someone else is doing,
>    to support something that is popular

Answer (score 0):

> well, a single word to describe the behaviour where you do something because everyone is also doing this, to the point where you do it without any clear reason, could be : Sheep

Comment: "Sheep" is a word to describe people who display this behaviour, not a word that actually describes the behaviour itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of "affectation," as in [definition 1.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/affectation) Though it differs slightly in its connotation, affectation has to do with pretense and attempting to project a particular appearance or generate a particular perception. Many people do things affectedly so that they can be perceived as being a part of the mainstream or "going along with the crowd," even if they don't genuinely understand what they're doing.

Comment: Comments about the down-votes would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who conforms that way could be called a "tool", although I can't find a reliable source for that. (Urban dictionary has one, though)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider:

> **drift** 5d :  an aimless course; especially :  a foregoing of any attempt at direction or control

from m-w.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the precise context in which you wish to use it, but in a political setting, "fence-sitter" fits the description.  They are on the fence until they know which side to stake and the choice is not based upon anything other than the popular position.  While many would say "uncommitted" and it is a definition found on-line, in the political sense a vote must be made the fence-sitter just waits until the popular position is clear.  It may sometimes mean a politician waiting for the "money" position to push him nefariously into agreement, but usually means the consesus of the populace.  The fence-sitter simply waits for others to make his choice.  Oh yeah add in "hipster:" the non-conforming conformer.  ;P

Answer (score -1):

echo:

Definition of echo (n)
Bing Dictionary
ech·o [ ékō ]
 1. repeated sound: the repetition of a sound caused by the reflection of sound waves from a surface
 2.something similar: something that repeats, imitates, or is reminiscent of something else
 3. returned signal: the signal reflected by an object struck by a radar
   transmission, or the image of this on a radar screen

The man's ideas echoed those of the majority. Hers echo the crowd she entertains.

Okay minus vote. WHat was wrong with my answer?

Comment: Not my downvote, but because I sympathise and have often received anonymous downvotes myself. I would say that the word echo is inappropriate in this context. People do not echo each other's behaviour, their beliefs or their preferences. You can copy, mimic or imitate their manners, their customs, their fashion choices. Echo by itself does not mean to follow the crowd, it is just repeating a sound, or maybe even an opinion heard. Hope this helps

Comment: An anomymous negative vote alone is just mean, duh, ok

Answer (score -1):

***robotic***

> "..to the point where you do it without any clear reason."

Answer (score -2):

*Floater* (thanks, CBS’s *Big Brother*!).

Comment: Could you give a definition of this word and provide a reference? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: I'll second last comment.  Please add a little more information about how the word would be used.