# looking for word that describes the phenomenon of taking sides with an aggressor

Tags: synonyms

I was wondering if there was a word that describes when people prefer to be "in the right hand of the devil than in his path"? Most of us have experienced bullying ourselves or witnessed it, or even watch it on youtube clips. Sometimes you see the victims being ignored until they retaliate, and then teachers break up the fight and punish both. But no one payed attention before hand.

I've had toxic friends in the past that would rip on me in a public setting trying when trying to hang out, in a non-kidding way. I basically had to put a stop to it myself because no one else would.

I feel like the word is cowardice but that can be a little broad and generic. Was wondering if there was one for that one type of situation.

Cheers

Comment: Please supply a sentence as you have requested a single word. Note that you have accepted an answer 9or 3) that apply to an a sentient agent, not an attitude / character flaw, which your 'cowardice' suggestion would almost mandate. Expressions for the practice have been given at [... going along with the crowd](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137107/single-word-for-going-along-with-the-crowd/137114#137114) (jumping on the bandwagon; conforming ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such people are *lapdogs*, *running-dogs*, *sidekicks*.

> *lapdog* = someone who is willing to do anything that a more important person tells them to do
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lapdog)

> *running-dog* = A servile follower or lackey.
>
> [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/running+dog)

> *sidekick* = a person closely associated with another as a subordinate or partner
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sidekick)

Of these three, I suggest that the first two are best because of the suggestion of complete canine subservience and obedience without any self-criticism.

Comment: All your suggestions refer to people who were *always* "on the side of the aggressor", but it seems to me OP is asking what to call those people who were previously either "friends" or simply "neutral", ***but who enthusiastically joined in the bullying once it started***. Maybe not quite there, but [***fair-weather friend***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fair-weather-friend) looks more promising to me.

Comment: ...riffing off which I found a reference to [***sunshine bigots*** and ***fair-weather lynch mobs***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fair-weather+lynch+mobs%22)